# What “a man who is happy to lie in the gutter, and watch while other climb mountain” is like?

Tags: meaning, metaphors

In Jeffery Archer’s fiction, “The Fourth Estate,” there is a scene Keith Townsend, one of two heroes featured as the owner of the largest communication empire in Australia responds the questions fired by a young female journalist (Kate Tulloh) about his sacking Sir Somerset, ex-chairman of Sydney-based newspaper company he aquired in the interview:

> “Didn’t Sir Somerset suffer roughly the same fate when you took over
>   the Chronicle? --
>
> He once described you,” said Kate, “as ‘**a man who is happy to lie in
>   the gutter and watch while others climb mountains**.”
>
> “I think you’ll find that Sir Somerset, like Shakespeare, is often
>   misquoted.”
>
> “It would be hard to prove either way,” said Kate, “as he’s also
>   dead.” – P339

Though it must be a metaphoric expression, what does “a man who is happy to lie in the gutter and watch while others climb mountains” mean in a couple of words? What character is it like?

Why in heaven’s name would an aggressive, ambitious young media mogul be happy to lie in the gutter and watch while others climb mountains? It should be the other way round. I have no idea.

Comment: It means, simply, that such a person has no ambition and is not troubled by that fact. The success of others does not move him to achieve anything himnself.

Comment: There can be some stigma attached with [*in the gutter*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+the+gutter). Sir Somerset may be saying that Keith Townsend dwells in the troubles of his life, while watching (maybe wishing to be like) others who aspire to higher, difficult things.

Comment: By the way, _in heaven's name_ is an idiom; _in the heaven's name_ isn't.

Comment: @ Colin Fine. You’re correct. ‘the’ is unnecessary. The beginner’s mistake.

Comment: @Colin, Yoichi: I just corrected that "idiomatic error", but only realised you'd already covered it when I scrolled down to add a comment. So here's my superfluous comment as well, for when a mod clears it all out eventually.

Comment: @Robusto: Given that "our hero" is *the owner of the largest communication empire in Australia* (i.e. - a fictional composite of Rupert Murdoch, Kerry Stokes, James Packer, etc.), I don't think *you're happy to lie in the gutter* can be read as *you have no ambition.*

Comment: @Fumble: I don't read Jeffrey Archer, and absent any extra-textual information how is one to say that Somerset is meant to represent Rupert Murdoch?

Comment: @Robusto: By *fictional composite* I didn't mean Archer explicitly intends us to understand his character as actually *being/representing* any or all of those (and/or maybe others, I don't know that much about Australian media moguls). I just meant that since OP's first sentence identifies Townsend as owner of the biggest (fictional) media empire in Australia, it's not likely the guy simply "lacks ambition". Apart from any extra-textual info, we're also told he casually sacks other bosses after takeovers, even those with knighthoods.

Comment: Robusto-san/ Fumble Fingers: Thanks for two EL&U mogul giving attention to my question. The expression, ‘a man who is happy to lie in the gutter and watch others climb --” reminds me of Japanese expression, ‘指を咥えて見る- Look on others’ success, biting one’s own thumb.’ It is unlikely that an aggressive, ambitious and young media owner is happy to lie in the gutter and watch others climb. I now come to realize that this is an old remark of Sir Summerset who was the owner of Sydney Chronicle which was overwhelming Townsend’s Melbourne Courier and Gazette before being purchased by Townsend.

Comment: Cont. It was the remark made before Townsend climbs up to the top of Australian media empire. To the eyes of Sir Summerset at that time, Townsend should be seen as only a wet-behind-the-ears local businessman who looks on others’ success biting his own thumb.

Answer (score 1):

It's an allusion to the standard idiom...

> [**gutter press**:](http://www.google.co.uk/#q=gutter+press&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&psj=1&ei=cEmuUbz-H4aY0AXb14DADg&ved=0CC0QkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47244034,d.d2k&fp=62ecb0084cfd0724&biw=1292&bih=916) *- reporters or newspapers engaging in sensational journalism, esp. accounts of the private lives of public figures*

Obviously *some* ["press barons"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/press+baron) get very rich selling tawdry gossip-mongering tabloid newspapers and magazines. If they're not ashamed, they're probably quite happy to watch the money roll in.